# How to decode "x26#39;" to the symbol ’ with java

Tags: java, escaping

I got some news rss, but the content have some text like "x26#39;", that is actually is a "'", I want to decode it in Java.

i tried StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4, but it does not work.

Comment: The text looks corrupt. `x26` should probably be `\x26` and represent `&` in whatever programming language generated the RSS. `&#39;` would then represent `'` as per HTML. The short of it is that the RSS is corrupt, and there is nothing you can reliably do to parse it, except tell the source that their RSS is corrupt and that they need to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, if that's really what you have, that's not valid in any language.

Comment: If you cannot get original RSS data changed then you can do some String#replace to cleanup the XML on your side.

Comment: Yes, I agree with all of you, thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters told, the input is corrupt. However you can do a workaround.. :-)

```
String rssInput = "These are the best news from FooBar x26#39; Top news";
String output = rssInput.replaceAll("x26#39;", "’");
```